# On STM32F7 DMA triggered by APB1 timers fails

Tags: timer, stm32, dma, stm32f7

I have STM32F7 Disco board with STM32F723IEK MCU. Trying to trigger a DMA request from a timer causes a DMA error, but only for timers from the APB1 group (TIM2 to TIM7 and others), that are connected to DMA1. Doing the same with TIM1 and TIM8, which are connected to DMA2, works fine. The error manifests itself as the TEIFx flag being set in the appropriate DMA LISR or HISR register and DMA immediately disabled after the first transaction. The NDTR register is decremented by one.

According to the datasheet, the TEIF error may be triggered by a "bus error". I understand this as e.g. trying to access a peripheral that is not accessible from the DMA bus. However, the same setup works well using DMA2 and TIM1/TIM8, without changing the DMA address. So the problem seems to be related to DMA request and not the data transaction itself. Given that there are lot of timer channels defined for DMA1, this should certainly work.

I have tried to vary DMA settings but this made no difference. The relevant portion of the test program is below. The full version https://github.com/ak-hard/stm32-dma-tim/blob/master/main.c is only slightly larger and have no dependencies except CMSIS and STM32 Device headers.

I wonder if someone can comment on or reproduce this problem.

```
const struct
{
    TIM_TypeDef *tim;
    DMA_TypeDef *dma;
    DMA_Stream_TypeDef *stream;
    unsigned channel;
} CFG = {
// uncomment the needed combination below, only TIM1 and TIM8 work
//    TIM1, DMA2, DMA2_Stream5, 6
    TIM8, DMA2, DMA2_Stream1, 7
//    TIM2, DMA1, DMA1_Stream1, 3
//    TIM2, DMA1, DMA1_Stream7, 3
//    TIM3, DMA1, DMA1_Stream2, 5
//    TIM4, DMA1, DMA1_Stream6, 2
//    TIM5, DMA1, DMA1_Stream0, 6
//    TIM5, DMA1, DMA1_Stream6, 6
//    TIM6, DMA1, DMA1_Stream1, 7
//    TIM7, DMA1, DMA1_Stream2, 1
//    TIM7, DMA1, DMA1_Stream4, 1
};

enum
{
    DMA_SxCR_DIR_P2M = 0,
    DMA_SxCR_PSIZE_WORD = DMA_SxCR_PSIZE_1,
    DMA_SxCR_MSIZE_WORD = DMA_SxCR_MSIZE_1,
};

#define DMA_SxCR_CHSEL_NUM(ch) ((ch) << DMA_SxCR_CHSEL_Pos)

uint32_t buf;

void start(void)
{
    SysTick->LOAD = 0xffffffu;
    SysTick->VAL = 0;
    SysTick->CTRL = 5;

    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN;
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_TIM1EN | RCC_APB2ENR_TIM8EN;
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM2EN | RCC_APB1ENR_TIM3EN | RCC_APB1ENR_TIM4EN | RCC_APB1ENR_TIM5EN
            | RCC_APB1ENR_TIM6EN | RCC_APB1ENR_TIM7EN;
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN | RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA2EN;

    LED_PORT->MODER   |= 1 << (2 * LED_PIN);
    LED_PORT->OSPEEDR |= 3 << (2 * LED_PIN); // fastest speed

    CFG.tim->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_ARPE;
    CFG.tim->ARR = 16;
    CFG.tim->PSC = 1000;
    CFG.tim->EGR = TIM_EGR_UG; // Generate Update Event to copy ARR to its shadow
    CFG.tim->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UDE;
    CFG.stream->CR |= DMA_SxCR_CHSEL_NUM(CFG.channel) | DMA_SxCR_DIR_P2M | DMA_SxCR_PSIZE_WORD | DMA_SxCR_MSIZE_WORD;
    CFG.stream->NDTR = 16;
    CFG.stream->PAR = (uint32_t) &GPIOA->IDR;
    CFG.stream->M0AR = (uint32_t) &buf;
    CFG.stream->CR |= DMA_SxCR_EN;
    CFG.tim->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;

    // wait until DMA state changes
    while (CFG.dma->LISR == 0 && CFG.dma->HISR == 0)
        delay_ms(1);

    // check for any TEIFx bits
    int error = (CFG.dma->LISR | CFG.dma->HISR) & 0x02080208;

    while (1)
    {
        LED_PORT->ODR ^= 1 << LED_PIN;
        delay_ms(error ? 100 : 500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There used to an answer here but it got deleted for some reason. Thanks to its author though.

Looking at the bus matrix, it becomes clear that the peripheral bus of the DMA1 is *only* connected to APB1. It is actually not a part of the matrix at all. This probably means that DMA1 can only handle transfers from/to APB1 peripherals. Since GPIO is an AHB peripheral, it is not accessible from DMA1. This should also apply to other APB2 (e.g. SPI1) and AHB peripherals (e.g. OTGFS). Normally, it does not make sense to access AHB or APB2 peripherals from DMA1 because their requests are not routed to DMA1. However, it may be needed for convoluted cases like GPIO by a timer.

I personally think this point could be made more obvious in the documentation.

Comment: Completely agree that the docs leave a lot to be desired. I am having this same trouble on the STM32H743, but I am getting it even when doing memory-to-memory transfers and haven't figured out how to work around it. (Ultimately I want to write 16-bits to `GPIOE->ODR` when a compare event from `HRTIM` fires -- timer works and event fires but transfer error occurs, and I see the same behavior when triggering from software.) "Figure 1. System arch..." makes it look like DMA1 can get to basically everything, so I'm still scratching my head and just blindly trying different things :/

Comment: Aha! It turns out that you have to be careful where the memory is located. When I defined a global array in my code it got placed in `DTCM` (0x20000000 -
0x2001FFFF). This article helped me resolve the problem: https://community.st.com/s/article/FAQ-DMA-is-not-working-on-STM32H7-devices